# Cannot delete file from docker instance

Tags: php, nginx, docker, symfony

I have trouble in my docker configuration. Everything works, but, when I try to manipulate (remove for example) a file on my windows host, I have a error message :

> File is open in VBoxHeadless.exe.

I use this : 
https://github.com/niklongstone/docker-nginx-php7-fpm.
A base of docker-compose with Nginx and Php7-fpm (for Symfony3 project).
Also, I have configuration file how look like this :

```
php-fpm:
    build: php-fpm
    ports:
        - 9000:9000
    volumes:
        - ../dashboard:/var/www/html/    
    links:
        - db
nginx:
    build: nginx
    ports:
        - 8080:80
    volumes:
        - ../dashboard:/var/www/html/        
    links:
        - php-fpm
db:
    image: mysql
    ports:
        - 3306:3306
    environment:
        MYSQL_DATABASE: dashboard
        MYSQL_USER: root
        MYSQL_PASSWORD: test
        MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: test
```

I have linked volume inform with volumes parameters.
Php-fpm and Nginx docker image is base in debian Jessie docker image.

For resume, I cannot delete Assets file (on web folder) via Windows (error: File is open in VBoxHeadless.exe) and I cannot delete Assets file via docker container (error 'File busy' (no more information with --verbose)).

And other information, I use Docker **Quickstart Terminal v.1.12.6**.

Specific file in title is an example, more file are concerned.

Comment: are you running virtualbox or docker with administrator privileges?  also, are you able to add new files on either side, e.g. add new file in windows and see it in the container and vice versa?  this seems like file permissions with the directory that may be resolved by running virtualbox in administrator mode may resolve.

Comment: Hi, GHETTO.CHiLD, I try to add basic .txt via Windows and Docker instance, and that's work; no permission problem. Unfortunatly, I can't run Docker Quickstart terminal as Admin (I think, by default, it's run as admin).

Comment: follow up, have you shared the drive accordingly in windows? https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/#/shared-drives

Comment: I try to install InstallDocker.msi but I have problem in installation. In tutorial, Docker recommend to install Docker quickstart terminal instead InstallDocker.msi. https://docs.docker.com/engine/getstarted/step_one/#/docker-for-windows

Comment: So, I don't have all machines configuration, shared-drives include.

Comment: this sounds like a `docker-machine` specific issue.  this may help but no guarantees since i use the latest docker on mac and windows as `docker-machine` has been deprecated. http://digitaldrummerj.me/docker-windows-mounting-directories/

Comment: I'm not sure if it's correct solution :( I can share my Symfony project with Docker container. I can create / edit but not delete assets files. I just try to delete php file and that's works. Apparently, problem come from assets. I use Gulp. Before generate assets, I can delete everything on assets files. But, when I use Gulp to genrate assets (with or whitout watch), files cannot be manipulated :(